# Conditionally calculate difference between multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've been struggling to conditionally calculate a time difference across multiple rows/columns.
I would like to calculate by id the time difference between an initial negative result and a subsequent positive. I've been trying to do this within dplyr but maybe I need another approach.

Code for data :

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
firstnegative <-c('T', 'F','F','F', 'F','F','F','F','T','F','F','F') 
organism <- c('neg', 'COVID', 'COVID', 'neg', 'COVID', 'neg', 'neg', 'neg', 'neg', 'neg', 'COVID', 'COVID')
date <- seq(as.Date("2020/3/1"), as.Date('2020/3/12'), "days")
data <- data.frame (id,date, organism, firstnegative)

 id       date organism  firstnegative
  1 2020-03-01      neg             T
  1 2020-03-02    COVID             F
  1 2020-03-03    COVID             F
  1 2020-03-04      neg             F
  2 2020-03-05    COVID             F
  2 2020-03-06      neg             F
  2 2020-03-07      neg             F
  2 2020-03-08      neg             F
  3 2020-03-09      neg             T
  3 2020-03-10      neg             F
  3 2020-03-11    COVID             F
  3 2020-03-12    COVID             F

Expected Result

 id       date organism  firstnegative   timediff
  1 2020-03-01      neg             T      1d
  1 2020-03-02    COVID             F
  1 2020-03-03    COVID             F
  1 2020-03-04      neg             F
  2 2020-03-05    COVID             F
  2 2020-03-06      neg             F
  2 2020-03-07      neg             F
  2 2020-03-08      neg             F
  3 2020-03-09      neg             T      2d
  3 2020-03-10      neg             F
  3 2020-03-11    COVID             F
  3 2020-03-12    COVID             F
```

The length between the first negative and subsequent positives is unknown and changes.  I can't assume a lead of 1.
Any thoughts/approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `id` you can find the first date of `'COVID'` and subtract it with first time `'T'` was present in `firstnegative`. Since we want value only on first row we `replace` rest of the values with `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(timediff = date[match('COVID', organism)] - 
                    date[match('T', firstnegative)],
         timediff = as.numeric(replace(timediff, -1L, NA)))

#      id date       organism firstnegative timediff
#   <dbl> <date>     <chr>    <chr>            <dbl>
# 1     1 2020-03-01 neg      T                    1
# 2     1 2020-03-02 COVID    F                   NA
# 3     1 2020-03-03 COVID    F                   NA
# 4     1 2020-03-04 neg      F                   NA
# 5     2 2020-03-05 COVID    F                   NA
# 6     2 2020-03-06 neg      F                   NA
# 7     2 2020-03-07 neg      F                   NA
# 8     2 2020-03-08 neg      F                   NA
# 9     3 2020-03-09 neg      T                    2
#10     3 2020-03-10 neg      F                   NA
#11     3 2020-03-11 COVID    F                   NA
#12     3 2020-03-12 COVID    F                   NA
```

Comment: thanks so much! I was not aware of the match function! Really appreciate this!